# UIPopoverController shifting with UINavigationController view pushing

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios, uipopovercontroller

I am using a `UINavigationController` within a `UIPopoverController` and pushing between three views within that navigation controller.
The first two views are the same width (320.0f) but the third view is the maximum 600.0f. I run into a very specific issue with things resizing coming back from the widest view. If I hit the back button the animation back to the smaller width forces the popover controller to animate to the left shifting the alignment away from the barbuttonitem the popover was originally presented from. How can I keep that popover controller glued to the right instead of always resizing off of the left most bound? Could there be an alignment type of flag on the navigation controller? Could it be something on the `ViewWillDisappear` on the widest view?

Here is the `ViewWillAppear` for the two smaller view controllers:

```
public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear (animated);
    SizeF vcSize = new SizeF(320.0f, 365.0f);
    ContentSizeForViewInPopover = vcSize;
    NavigationController.ContentSizeForViewInPopover = vcSize;
}
```

And here is the `ViewWillAppear` for the larger view controller:

```
public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear (animated);
    SizeF vcSize = new SizeF(600.0f, 700.0f);
    ContentSizeForViewInPopover = vcSize;        
    NavigationController.ContentSizeForViewInPopover = vcSize;
}
```

Any help... as always, is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you try only `self.ContentSizeForViewInPopover = vcSize;`? Remove last line `NavigationController.ContentSizeForViewInPopover = vcSize;` Use that line when you create your popover.

Comment: Obviously `NavigationController` has to be an instance.

Comment: I believe since the self view controller is nested within the nav controller which is nested inside the popover controller I need to set it for both. Regardless setting it only for the self VC has no effect and the popover actually resizes to it's default size.